# DynamoDB provisioned Read/Write Capacity Units exceeded unexpectedly

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I run a program that sends data to dynamodb using api gateway and lambdas.

All the data sent to the db is small, and only sent from about 200 machines.

I'm still using free tier and sometimes unexpectedly in the middle of the month I'm start getting an higher provisioned read / write capacity and then from this day I pay a constant amount each day until the end of the month.

Can someone understand from the image below what happened in the 03/13 that caused this pike in the charts and caused these provisioned to rise from 50 to 65?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell what happened based on those charts alone, but some things to consider:

You may not be aware of the new "PAY_PER_REQUEST" billing mode option for DynamoDB tables which allows you to mostly forget about manually provisioning your throughput capacity: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-dynamodb-on-demand-no-capacity-planning-and-pay-per-request-pricing/

Also, might not make sense for your use case, but for free tier projects I've found it useful to proxy all writes to DynamoDB through an SQS queue (use the queue as an event source for a Lambda with a reserved concurrency that is compatible with your provisioned throughput). This is easy if your project is reasonably event-driven, i.e. build your DynamoDB request object/params, write to SQS, then have the next step be a Lambda that is triggered from the DynamoDB stream (so you aren't expecting a synchronous response from the write operation in the first Lambda). Like this:

Example serverless config for SQS-triggered Lambda:

```
dynamodb_proxy:
  description: SQS event function to write to DynamoDB table '${self:custom.dynamodb_table_name}'
  handler: handlers/dynamodb_proxy.handler
  memorySize: 128
  reservedConcurrency: 95 # see custom.dynamodb_active_write_capacity_units
  environment:
    DYNAMODB_TABLE_NAME: ${self:custom.dynamodb_table_name}
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:PutItem
      Resource:
        - Fn::GetAtt: [ DynamoDbTable, Arn ]
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - sqs:ReceiveMessage
        - sqs:DeleteMessage
        - sqs:GetQueueAttributes
      Resource:
        - Fn::GetAtt: [ DynamoDbProxySqsQueue, Arn ]
  events:
    - sqs:
        batchSize: 1
        arn:
          Fn::GetAtt: [ DynamoDbProxySqsQueue, Arn ]
```

Example write to SQS:

```
await sqs.sendMessage({
  MessageBody: JSON.stringify({
    method: 'putItem',
    params: {
      TableName: DYNAMODB_TABLE_NAME,
      Item: {
        ...attributes,
        created_at: {
          S: createdAt.toString(),
        },
        created_ts: {
          N: createdAtTs.toString(),
        },
      },
      ...conditionExpression,
    },
  }),
  QueueUrl: SQS_QUEUE_URL_DYNAMODB_PROXY,
}).promise();
```

SQS-triggered Lambda:

```
import retry from 'async-retry';
import { getEnv } from '../lib/common';
import { dynamodb } from '../lib/aws-clients';

const {
  DYNAMODB_TABLE_NAME
} = process.env;

export const handler = async (event) => {
  const message = JSON.parse(event.Records[0].body);

  if (message.params.TableName !== env.DYNAMODB_TABLE_NAME) {
    console.log(`DynamoDB proxy event table '${message.params.TableName}' does not match current table name '${env.DYNAMODB_TABLE_NAME}', skipping.`);
  } else if (message.method === 'putItem') {
    let attemptsTaken;
    await retry(async (bail, attempt) => {
      attemptsTaken = attempt;
      try {
        await dynamodb.putItem(message.params).promise();
      } catch (err) {
        if (err.code && err.code === 'ConditionalCheckFailedException') {
          // expected exception
          // if (message.params.ConditionExpression) {
          //   const conditionExpression = message.params.ConditionExpression;
          //   console.log(`ConditionalCheckFailed: ${conditionExpression}. Skipping.`);
          // }
        } else if (err.code && err.code === 'ProvisionedThroughputExceededException') {
          // retry
          throw err;
        } else {
          bail(err);
        }
      }
    }, {
      retries: 5,
      randomize: true,
    });

    if (attemptsTaken > 1) {
      console.log(`DynamoDB proxy event succeeded after ${attemptsTaken} attempts`);
    }
  } else {
    console.log(`Unsupported method ${message.method}, skipping.`);
  }
};
```

Comment: You're not synchronously waiting for dynamodb to return but you're waiting for the message to be put in SQS. I need to run some tests but I am sure writing to Dynamo is faster than writing to SQS, even if only by a couple of milliseconds. So, what's the gain here?

Comment: I found an article by someone who actually ran the benchmarks and he said he got 60-70ms latency upon writing to SQS. DynamoDB write latency is in a single digit millisecond, meaning SQS is at least 6.7 times slower. https://softwaremill.com/amazon-sqs-performance-latency/

Comment: And this is from the official FAQ -> What is the typical latency for Amazon SQS? : ***Typical latencies for SendMessage, ReceiveMessage, and DeleteMessage API requests are in the tens or low hundreds of milliseconds***. https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/

Comment: @ThalesMinussi Your question makes no statement about low latency being a goal nor did I claim this solution would reduce latency. I recommended a way to have tighter control on the concurrency of DynamoDB operations using Lambda's reserved concurrency feature (too many lambdas writing to DynamoDB will cause throughput exceptions). If you care about latency, ditch free-tier or update your question with specifics.

Comment: You have to pay more attention as I am not the one who asked the question. Also, I mentioned the latency because that was the ONLY thing you said about adding SQS to this architecture just because you did not want to wait for DynamoDB to return, but DynamoDB returns WAY faster than SQS, so your point is completely nonsense.

Comment: @ThalesMinussi I said no such thing. I never said anything about speed at all. lol #youareverysmart, also, where is your suggestion to the OP?

Comment: "so you aren't expecting a synchronous response from the write operation in the first Lambda". But then you are waiting for the message to be put in SQS. You're so lost.

Comment: @ThalesMinussi that has nothing to do with speed, it has to do with decoupling your functions so they do 1 thing only. this is a principal of event driven design.

Comment: When that MAKES sense. Here it doesn't make any sense at all. But I am done spending my time with you, you're not worth it. Best!